# Effect of the Sun on the motion of bodies on the Earth

Tags: gravity, acceleration, astrophysics, solar-system, free-fall

Does a body at the surface of the Earth fall at a slower rate when the Sun is at its zenith (that is when the side of the Earth that the body is on is turned towards the Sun and the body is directly facing it) and does it fall faster when it's the opposite? Is it a practically significant change?

Answer (score 1):

If an object were held still and then released, it would accelerate towards the sun at about $0.006$ m/s$^2$, at one astronomical unit (earth - sun distance).

An object accelerates towards the earth at about  $9.8$ m/s$^2$, so if the earth were stationary the accelerations towards the earth for objects either side would be $9.806$ and $9.794$ m/s$^2$.

However we must take into account that the earth is accelerating towards the sun with the $0.006$ m/s$^2$ value, so the end result is that there is no difference in the two accelerations of objects towards the earth.